# postman not sending the data to mongodb

Tags: api, rest, postman

This is the data that I want to send in postman

> 

```
` {
    "username":"mingli",
    "email":"mingli@yahoo.com",
    "password":"123456789"
    }`
```

This is the error I got in postman when I send my data

> 

```
{
"errors": {
    "password": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `password` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `password` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "password"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "password"
    }
},
"_message": "User validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required."
```

}

I am trying my data to mongoDB.However, it return me an error where password is required( password entered)

> This is my user model file
> const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isSeller: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
 { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

> This is my router file
> //ROUTER

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");




.get("/",  async (req, res) => {
const query = req.query.new;
    try {
      const users = query
        ? await User.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(5)
        : await User.find();
      res.status(200).json(users);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });



module.exports = router;
```

This is the user file

```
//REGISTER
   router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
   const newUser = new User({
   username: req.body.username,
   email: req.body.email,
   });


  //save user information in db
      try {
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      res.status(201).json(savedUser);
      }catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
   });

//LOGIN

    router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne(
            {
            userName: req.body.user_name
        }
    );

    !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong User Name");


    const inputPassword = req.body.password;
    
    originalPassword != inputPassword && 
        res.status(401).json("Wrong Password");


    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;  
 ;

}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
}

});
```

Comment: trying to manipulate the db

Comment: yes i am trying so

Comment: my bad I forget to add the user file

Comment: you are not passing password when registering?

Comment: I solved it but anyway thank you